# Adding Wordpress header into a subfolder page

Tags: wordpress, header

Okay. I have wordpress installed on the root. I also have uploaded a subfolder within wordpress. www.mysite.com/subfolder/  I want to be able to add some php pages inside the subfolder because I need it to call some scripts. I just want to be able to add the wordpress header into it. The pages come up but when I add the wordpress header it all goes blank or just does nothing. 
I have tried... 
    '

```
<?php include 'http://www.mywebsite.org/wp-blog-header.php'; ?>
<?php require('http://www.mywebsite.org/wp-blog-header.php');?>
```

and tried

```
<?php include 'http://www.mywebsite.org/wp-content/themes/MYTHEME/header.php'; ?>
<?php require('http://www.mywebsite.org/wp-content/themes/MYTHEME/header.php');?>
```

and

```
<?php include './wp-content/themes/MYTHEME/header.php'; ?>
<?php require('./wp-content/themes/MYTHEME/header.php');?>
```

Nothing seems to be working.

Any help would be great...Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the problem is you're including the URL to `wp-blog-header.php`, you should instead include the relative path, then call `get_header();` as usual. So you should have something like this:

```
<?php
require('/the/path/to/your/wp-blog-header.php');
get_header();
?>
```

Check out the [Integrating WordPress with Your Website](http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_Wordpress_with_Your_Website) Codex entry.

Comment: Thank you @michaelrmcneill ... This led me to the right path. I used                                                                    <?php
    require('../wp-blog-header.php');
 get_header();
     ?>